# How to handle arrays in the configuration? (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, environment-variables

I created a new configuration file, which is a nested array with string keys. The `.env` can not store arrays, that is why I created the `config/myconfig.php`. I access the data with `Config::get('myconfig')`

Unfortunatelly this config is not the same for every customer. Since I can not put this array into the `.env`, I manually update the config php file, where it is needed.

What is the best way to define an environment variable, which is not a simple string, but a nested array?

Comment: There's no reason you can't store JSON strings in your .env file if you need to. You can call `json_decode()` on it. But be ware, this may have unintended consequences.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/return-array-from-env) could help you.

Comment: Just curious, what kind of environment variable are you trying to store as an array? Are the values not scalar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the same trouble and fixed following [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/return-array-from-env) post at Laracast and I think it fits your problem too.

Basically I created a custom config file in the config folder, like:

```
return [     
    env('KEY') => [
        env('KEY_ONE') => env('VALUE_ONE'),     
        env('KEY_TWO') => env('VALUE_TWO')  
    ]
};
```

And in my .env file:

```
KEY=VALUE
KEY_ONE=VALUE_ONE
KEY_TWO=VALUE_TWO
```

Simple as that, then you can access to the array in your application calling the config variable like:

```
Config::get('configfile_name.key');
```

or directly to the array index:

```
Config::get('configfile_name.key.key_one');
```

Comment: thanks a lot for helping and it is working according to my requirements

Comment: i want to get all configs in one of the config file as an array